# Is it legal to pass `std::shared_future` as a reference to functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, future

[Passing `std::shared_future` by value](https://godbolt.org/z/q45cxz4hn) is legal, since `std::shared_future` is copyable.

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int factorial(std::shared_future<int> sf)
{
    int res = 1;
    int num = sf.get();

    for(int i=num; i>1; i--)
    {
        res *= i;
    }

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prs;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> vec;


    std::shared_future<int> sf{prs.get_future()};
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, factorial, sf));
    }  
    
    prs.set_value(5);

    for(auto& fut: vec)
    {
        std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is it legal to [pass `std::shared_future` as a reference](https://godbolt.org/z/eeYvT1TaT) to functions?

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int factorial(std::shared_future<int>& sf)
{
    int res = 1;
    int num = sf.get();

    for(int i=num; i>1; i--)
    {
        res *= i;
    }

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prs;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> vec;


    std::shared_future<int> sf{prs.get_future()};
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, factorial, std::ref(sf)));
    }  

    prs.set_value(5);

    for(auto& fut: vec)
    {
        std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The code snippet compiles and **seems** work well. Could somebody shed some light on this mattter?

***UPDATED***:

For `shared_ptr`, many aspects need to be considered when choosing to passing as a reference or passing by value.

What about `shared_future`? How to make the choice?

Comment: Yes. There are no exceptions for `std::future` (actually, for any type) concerning the fundamentals of C++. Using the same object from different threads could become a possible cause of issues though.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I see. For `shared_future`, which one is better, passing as a reference or passing by value?

Comment: you can prevent a user from making a copy  but not from taking a reference, hence a type where passing by reference would be broken can be considered completely broken

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I can understand that *you can prevent a user from making a copy, but not from taking a reference*. I don't really understand what do you mean by ***"a type where passing by reference would be broken can be considered completely broken"***? Could you please explain that in simpler words?

Comment: a reference is just an alias. Actually I don't know how taking a reference could be not ok. However, if it would then its the class fault not the users. Anyhow, I suggest you to forget about "better" (an actually not that useful term), but consider if you want to make a copy or not make a copy

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I see. Sorry for my poor English. I updated the session named `UPDATED`.

Comment: There might be a difference between using the same `shared_future` (if taken by reference) and using copies of `shared_future` (if taken by value). In the former case you might need some synchronization to access the same object from different threads, and in the latter case such synchronization might not be needed because a different object is accessed. Cppreference [reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future): Access to the same shared state from multiple threads is safe if each thread does it **through its own copy** of a shared_future object. (emphasis is mine)

Comment: forget everything I said :P I am writing an answer....

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future/wait):

> Calling wait on the same `std::shared_future` from multiple threads is
> not safe; the intended use is for each thread that waits on the same
> shared state to have a copy of a `std::shared_future`.

A `shared_future` is already behaving like a "reference" to some shared state. However, its intended use is that each thread uses its own copy, such that they can call `wait` and other methods without getting into their way.

Comment: *Anyhow your usage of it is kinda **backwards**. std::async does already return a std::future that you should use **instead of** passing a reference to another future object. *Sorry, I can't fully understand what you mean. Could you please expalin that in simpler words for me?

Comment: @John sorry, don't know how to explain better. Your code creates a `std::future` then creates a `std::shared_future` from it, then passes a reference to `std::async`. This isnt intended usage. Instead of creating a `std::future` your own you should use the one returned by `std::async` as in the example

Comment: @John `std::shared_future<int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ return fib(43); });` thats the future you should use. You don't need to pass one manually because `std::async` already returns one to hold the result of the call

Comment: I am quite sure that you misunderstand the code snippet in the post.You mess up the `std::future`s in the aforementioned code snippet, one is a input argument, the other is a return value, they have no relations at all.  The code snippet is seen in a tutorial. Passing an `std::shared_future` to the `std::async`(i.e. finally  passing to `factorial()`) is to learn that `std::future`&`std::shared_future` could be passed as a parameter to `std::async`. How do you think about it?

Comment: @John oh right. Nevertheless the first part of the answer is correct. `get` calls `wait` and this shoudlnt be done on the same object by multiple threads.

Comment: I agree with you. Thank you for the detailed explanation. My understanding of this matter is at a different level with your generous help.

Comment: You need to check validity `.valid()` before `.wait()` or `.get()`

Comment: @Sohailsil true but not that relevant here. The question is about several threads using the same `std::future` vs several threads using different `std::future`s that refer to the same shared state